# Protecting information after installer VB 2012

Tags: vb.net, installation, installshield

When in make Installer on my project in Visual Basic 2012. I'm using InstallShield - and filed that i need to create the program are only "Debug or Realese" Folder. But there are files "program.exe.config" files. Everyone can open it if he has VB or program that can open VB 2012 files. In those files there is an information about connection to server that program makes. So they have my server name and mine user/password that gives access to mine sql server. Can i make the line with server information crypted and it still workes to avoid - changing server/logging into my server.

Or how can i block the files while i'm making the installer. - So they could not open them.

Answer (score 0):

Store encrypted password and username in config file. And decrypt them inside code right before connection. This should make the trick.

Make the same with  server name if you'd like to.

Comment: What do you mean to encrypt pass/user and server. 
Open config file - set *****, but in code store them as real one :? Wont they change after rebuild the program.

Comment: I tried to make it that way ->open config file->change the password to "******" but it doesnt work